# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'get_name'

Tags: javascript, dopostback

my javascript function is crapping out after my for loop with the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'get_name'

It is not running the dopostback

```
function fnCollapseAll() {
    var currentBehavior = null;
    var allBehaviors = Sys.Application.getComponents();
    for (var loopIndex = 0; loopIndex <= allBehaviors.length; loopIndex++) {
        currentBehavior = allBehaviors[loopIndex];
        if (currentBehavior.get_name() == "CollapsiblePanelBehavior") {
            if (!currentBehavior.get_Collapsed()) {
                currentBehavior.set_Collapsed(true);
            }
        }
    }
    __doPostBack('<%=m_CollapseAllDIV.ClientID%>', 'Collapse All');
 }
```

Comment: The problem is clear, the object doesn't have `.get_name()` method.

Comment: How is the object `currentBehavior` defined ?

Comment: `allBehaviors[loopIndex]` is `undefined` in the last round of your loop

Comment: @Andreas Am I doing the for loop wrong, why is this undefined here?

Comment: @Andreas the error still occurs on the following loop

`for (var loopIndex = 0; loopIndex < allBehaviors.length; loopIndex++)`

Comment: That shouldn't be the solution for your problem. But after fixing the problem with the missing `.get_name()` you would have had encountered the next error because of the undefined `allBehaviors` in the last run.

Comment: @Andreas i dont understand why `allBehaviors` would be undefined in the first place, I only loop until that arrays length?

Comment: `currentBehaviour` would be `undefined` not `allBehaviors` The first index of the array starts with zero and not one. Because of this the index of the last item in the array is `.length - 1` As your condition for the loop is `<= length` `loopIndex` equals `length` in the last round of the loop. But this is one step to far which

Comment: The same issue occurs with the following code where the for loop is changed to < rather than <=